# Why is this registry check returning null?

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm checking if there's an entry in the registry so I'll know if I need to install SQL Compact on a Windows Mobile Device, but this request just returns null.

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition v3.5 [EN]", "MajorVersion", "NONE")
```

This confuses me, since shouldn't it return a string with "NONE" if it can't find the key?

Comment: Not according to the **documentation**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx

Comment: @AndrewMorton Whoops. Pesky documentation..

Comment: You might want to delete your question before it gets downvoted due to not checking the docs ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Actually I did read the docs. I generally do. I just glossed over part some how. Oh well, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: or Andrew should convert his comment to an answer, and cost can mark it the correct answer, since it is...